# How do I loop through nested array and insert id and parentId for each level?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

How do I loop through nested array and insert id and parentId for each level?

This is what I have:

```
{
    "locations": [
        {
            "name": "Europe",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Denmark",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Copenhagen",
                            "population": [
                                {
                                    "people": "602481"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "South Europe",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "Spain",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Madrid",
                                    "population": [
                                        {
                                            "people": "6550000"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Barcelona",
                                    "population": [
                                        {
                                            "people": "5515000"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Asia",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "East Asia",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "China",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Beijing",
                                    "population": [
                                        {
                                            "people": "21540000"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what I want:

```
{
    "locations": [
        {
            "id": "AP1",
            "name": "Europe",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "AP1.1",
                    "parentId": "AP1",
                    "name": "Denmark",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": "AN1",
                            "parentId": "AP1.1",
                            "name": "Copenhagen",
                            "population": [
                                {
                                    "people": "602481"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": "AP1.2",
                    "parentId": "AP1",
                    "name": "South Europe",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": "AP1.2.1",
                            "parentId": "AP1.2",
                            "name": "Spain",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "id": "AN2",
                                    "parentId": "AP1.2.1",
                                    "name": "Madrid",
                                    "population": [
                                        {
                                            "people": "6550000"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "AN3",
                                    "parentId": "AP1.2.1",
                                    "name": "Barcelona",
                                    "population": [
                                        {
                                            "people": "5515000"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "AP2",
            "name": "Asia",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "AP2.1",
                    "parentId": "AP2",
                    "name": "East Asia",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "id": "AP2.1.1",
                            "parentId": "AP2.1",
                            "name": "China",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "id": "AN4",
                                    "parentId": "AP2.1.1",
                                    "name": "Beijing",
                                    "population": [
                                        {
                                            "people": "21540000"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm relatively new to JavaScript, I only know how to loop through the the first array which is Europe and Asia by using a basic for loop. How do i actually loop all the way through the hierarchy?

Comment: You need a recursion (a function with an if-statement that calls itself in one of the if cases but not the other).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
const obj = {
  "locations": [{
      "name": "Europe",
      "children": [{
          "name": "Denmark",
          "children": [{
            "name": "Copenhagen",
            "population": [{
              "people": "602481"
            }]
          }]
        },
        {
          "name": "South Europe",
          "children": [{
            "name": "Spain",
            "children": [{
                "name": "Madrid",
                "population": [{
                  "people": "6550000"
                }]
              },
              {
                "name": "Barcelona",
                "population": [{
                  "people": "5515000"
                }]
              }
            ]
          }]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Asia",
      "children": [{
        "name": "East Asia",
        "children": [{
          "name": "China",
          "children": [{
            "name": "Beijing",
            "population": [{
              "people": "21540000"
            }]
          }]
        }]
      }]
    }
  ]
}

function recur(arr, prevId = undefined) {
  let countId = 0;

  arr.forEach(item => {
    countId++;
    
    if (prevId) {
      item.id = prevId + '.' + countId;
      item.parentId = prevId;
    } else {
      item.id = countId.toString();
    }

    if ('children' in item && item.children.length > 0) {
      recur(item.children, item.id);
    }
  });
}

recur(obj.locations);
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj, undefined, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

And it is untrue that you **need** recursion. You could do this iteratively as well, if you want to learn about that you may want to start here: [Tree Traversal on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal).

---

**EDIT:**
Just noticed that there's supposed to be a naming scheme regarding ids, but since you didn't specify what it is, I can't help with that. Basically you'd need to expand this function with conditionals that'll determine actual string in id.

Comment: Aaah okay so you check if there is a 'children', and if it contains anything, and if those two are true, you repeat the function inside. and the forEach makes sure that all items are looped through... Smart, i get the idea thank you very much!!!